# Cannot get Ubuntu to install

Tags: boot, system-installation, 20.10

I have an old laptop on which I want to install Ubuntu.
I downloaded 20.10 and used Rufus to make a bootable flash drive.

I can boot fine off of the USB, but after installation when it's time to reboot I get a "Operation System not found" message. (That wasn't a typo).

I have converted the hard drive from GPT to MBR.
I have used Rufus to 'burn' the ISO to the flash drive using both MBR and GPT methods.

Nothing helps.
I have also tried with a brand-new hard drive. Same issue.
Downgraded the BIOS didn't help.

The laptop I'm using is a Dell Inspiron 14z (service tag: GN0JTQ1). It has 6GB of DDR3 and a 500GB hard drive.

I've been at it for 2 days now, and I can't get the system to work.

If I try to reinstall, the Ubuntu setup detects the other Ubuntu 20.10 install. It's just when it has to boot that the issue appears.

When installing Windows 10 no such issue is occurred.

I don't think I have a UEFI enabled system as the BIOS setup doesn't contain any Secure Boot options...

I'm very new to Ubuntu, so any (detailed, step-by-step, dumbed down) help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI/BIOS to latest version available from Dell. You should also update SSD firmware. I used gpt with my BIOS only system from 2006, so that is not related. You do need drives set to AHCI, not RAID nor Intel RST. If newer than 2012, then it is UEFI as Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives. Many say "Windows" or "Other" as Secure boot setting. Use "Other".

Comment: The drives are set to AHCI. I don't see any 'Other' or 'Windows' option.

Comment: Update: Booting from DVD doesn't help. I ended up installing Fedora, which didn't cause any issues. I don't know what the issue is. For now I'll stick with Fedora, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

The "Operation System not found" message tells me that you have a relatively old BIOS in that machine, and it's looking for a boot partition on your hard drive despite the fact you're trying to boot from USB. When you converted the hard drive from GPT to MBR, I'm assuming you wiped the drive of all partitions (as that's exactly what I would do, too) and rebooted the machine with the goal of installing Ubuntu on a "fresh" drive.

Speaking from far too much experience with Dell notebooks, you now have two options:

1. Boot from a Live DVD (not USB ... because the older BIOSes are asinine like that)
2. (Somehow) create a primary partition on the hard drive and mark it bootable. You do not need to have anything on this partition, nor does it need to be formatted with any particular file system, but a bootable primary partition must exist.

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: How do I go about with point 2? Do I do that with the Live DVD during Ubuntu setup? How big should the partition be?